# Change image size of image inside a dive by Css

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a project with Flutter web. When Flutter web is opened the first time it takes a few seconds to load so I want to show a spinner loader. I've tried adding the following to the index.html:

```
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loader" />
  </div>
```

with these styles:

```
.loading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-image: url("img/images.jpeg");
    background-size: contain;
    resize: both;
    padding: 25px;
  }

  .loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-top: 16px solid #8a2245;
    border-right: 16px solid white;
    border-bottom: 16px solid #8a2245;
    border-left: 16px solid white;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```

But `background-image` has bad size and I want it to be small and located in de middle of spinner. How can I do that?

[image: Incorrect loader image]

Comment: I'm going to remove the flutter and flutter-web tags as I don't think anyone with experience in those fields could answer this question. This question seems like an html/css question that just happens to be a loader for flutter web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set size of background image using `background-size` property in `px` (pixel) or `%` (percentage). And align the image to center using `background-position: center;`